# Reverse Proxy - General Question

Tags: network

After a reverse proxy has authenticated a user, does the reverse proxy continue to interact with network traffic?

Meaning, if I continue to access resources on a server, will the reverse proxy be included in the network flow?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about servers and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Roger that. Sorry for the wrong audience direction. Was fed some suspect information regarding this topic and needed some confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy - forward or reverse - always "interacts" with the traffic: the proxy terminates the incoming "from client" connection, creates a new outgoing "to server" connection and passes the data in between.